# How to apply function to index named with at-sign in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have dataframe like below (got from the other app.).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3], '@y':[4,5,6]})
df
Out[27]:
   x  @y
0  1   4
1  2   5
2  3   6
```

my function is below and it can apply to df.x.

```
def my_func(v):
  return pd.Sereis(v*2)

df.apply(lambda z: my_func(z.x), axis=1)
Out[23]:
    0
0  2
1  4
2  6
```

But I cannot access df.@y attribute.

```
df.apply(lambda z: my_func(z.@y), axis=1)

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How to access @y?

Comment: Use double `[]` like `z['@y]'`

Comment: df.attr is the same df['attr']. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome! Generally if use `[]` it working with all columns names.

Comment: Yes, like @jezrael said, try using `[]` as `.` doesnot work with column names having spaces.